# Couchbase Bulk Get documents using Reactive Flux

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to bulk get documents using Reactive to improve the performance. Its working fine but it's intermittently giving empty result.

I am passing list of ids which contain 100 id's per request. I am using Couchbase 6.6 and SDK 3.1.2 and java 11.

Below is my bulk get code. Can someone please help me ?

Also please suggest if there are any faster way to fetch bulk document's.

```
Flux.fromIterable(ids)
            .flatMap(
                key ->
                    collection
                        .reactive()
                        .get(key, getOptions)
                        .map(getResult -> getResult.contentAs(targetClass))
                        .onErrorResume( ex -> Mono.empty()
                           ))
            .collectList()
            .block();
```

Comment: Looks like that code just ignores errors, so it will be hard to know why the result is intermittently empty. What do you see if you change your `onErrorResume` code to include `ex.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: Thanks @dnault. I have tried with logging exception inside `onErrorResume` but I did not get any logs also. `onErrorResume(e -> { logger.error("Exception inside Reactive Get ", e); return Mono.empty(); }))`